# Синтетика (синтетический наркотик) нужно ли закавычить?

Tags: кавычки

Синтетика (как синтетический наркотик) нужно ли закавычить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без контекста трудно дать однозначный ответ. Кавычки не нужны, если понятно, что речь идет о синтетическом продукте. "Это натуральный продукт, а это синтетика", "Я ношу синтетику, "Я курю синтетику".

Если у вас заголовок **Неуловимая "синтетика"**, то я бы поставил кавычки, так как, по-моему, здесь слово употреблено не в своем прямом значении (просто *синтетика* — это синтетические материалы вообще).

Comment: в заголовке текста - неуловимая синтетика. (думаю, следует закавычить, речь идет о методах определения новых видов наркотиков)

Comment: как быть в моем случае?

Comment: да, я поставила. Спасибо